# Object not holding instance when accessed through method

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I made a Model Class "RestaurentList" which populates two collections with data from a json file.
After instantiating an object to the class in my ViewModel i databind the collections to an ItemsControl.

Everything in the above works fine, but when i call the method populatePartialList from the object in my ViewModel, it doesn't contain any of the data from when i instantiated the object. 
This means, that when my method tries to repopulate the PartialList, it can't because it doesn't find the data from FullList.

Edit: I left out some of the code as you can see with the comment tags.
I just want to give you an understanding of how i am doing this.

My question basicly is, why the object doesn't contain any data when i'm calling the method populatePartialList.

My guess it's got something to do with the fact, that i am databinding the List to an ItemsControl and therefor can't access it anymore? What should do in that case then? I'm trying to make a very simple pagination

Edit to the above; I tried removing my Bind and i still can't reach the data.

Model:

```
public class RestaurentList
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Restaurent> _fullList = new ObservableCollection<Restaurent>();

        private ObservableCollection<Restaurent> _partialList = new ObservableCollection<Restaurent>();

        public ObservableCollection<Restaurent> FullList
        {
            get { return _fullList; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Restaurent> PartialList
        {
            get { return _partialList; }
        }

        public RestaurentList()
        {
            populateList();
        }

        public void populatePartialList(int fromValue = 1)
        {
            int collectionAmount = _fullList.Count;
            int itemsToShow = 2;
            fromValue = (fromValue > collectionAmount ? 1 : fromValue);

            foreach (Restaurent currentRestaurent in _fullList)
            {
                int currentId = Convert.ToInt32(currentRestaurent.UniqueId);
                if (currentId == fromValue || (currentId > fromValue && currentId <= (fromValue + itemsToShow)-1))
                {
                    _partialList.Add(currentRestaurent);
                }
            }
        } 

        private async void populateList()
        {
            // Get json data

            foreach (JsonValue restaurentValue in jsonArray)
            {
                // populate full list

                foreach (JsonValue menuValue in restaurentObject["Menu"].GetArray())
                {
                    // populate full list
                }
                this._fullList.Add(restaurent);
            }
            populatePartialList();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
```

View Model:

```
class ViewModelDefault : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private RestaurentList _list;

        public ObservableCollection<Restaurent> List
        {
            get { return _list.PartialList; }
        }


        public ViewModelDefault()
        {  
            _list = new RestaurentList();
            _list.populatePartialList(2); // This is where i don't see the data from RestaurentList
        }

        #region Notify
    }
```

Edit for Jon:

```
public RestaurentList()
        {
            PopulatePartialList();
        }

        public async void PopulatePartialList(int fromValue = 1)
        {
            await PopulateList();
            int collectionAmount =  _fullList.Count;
            int itemsToShow = 2;
            fromValue = (fromValue > collectionAmount ? 1 : fromValue);

            foreach (Restaurent currentRestaurent in _fullList)
            {
                int currentId = Convert.ToInt32(currentRestaurent.UniqueId);
                if (currentId == fromValue || (currentId > fromValue && currentId <= (fromValue + itemsToShow)-1))
                {
                    _partialList.Add(currentRestaurent);
                }
            }
        } 

        private async Task PopulateList()
        {
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, restaurant ends with `ant`, not `ent` - now would be a good time to fix the name. I'd also strongly recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions for methods, i.e. `PopulatePartialList` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the line of code before your call to `populatePartialList`:

```
_list = new RestaurentList();
```

You've created a new instance of `RestaurentList`. That will have called `populateList()`, but *not* waited for it complete. Assuming your real implementation of `populateList` contains `await` operations, that means your call to `populatePartialList(2)` will almost certainly occur before the data is ready.

You need to think about how the asynchrony works here, and how you *want* it to work. Note that while you can't have an asynchronous constructor, you could have an asynchronous static method... that may well be a better idea for both `ViewModelDefault` and `RestaurentList`.

Comment: That makes sense. I am only just learning about Asynchrony, I'm sorry if that may have been too obvious.

Comment: @Mathias: Very little in asynchrony is obvious ;) Expect it to take a while to get your head around, to be honest...

Comment: Hehe. Thanks for the tip though.
I have to be sure that I understand what to do here.
If i make my populatePartialList work async, how do i make it wait on the FullList being populated first?

Comment: I made an edit to the post, where i made populateList into a Task, which i then execute with await in my populatePartialList. It's not functioning how i want it too though. I haven't analyzed it completely yet.

Comment: @Mathias: I think it would be worth asking about this in a different question - but fundamentally the problem is that `PopulatePartialList` is an `async void` method, rather than returning a task to await... and you're still calling it from a constructor, which couldn't await it anyway.

Comment: Okay with my recent solution i am continually adding to the FullList everytime i wish to populate my partial list. I will somehow have to  check if fullList has allready been populated, which is the problem as it runs async.

Comment: if I don't instantiate it within the constructor i would have to call the method, before i can databind the data. That would work fine until the point i wish to repopulate my List. (I guess?) I'm trying to think of a solution through your clues hehe.

Comment: Again, this sounds like you should be thinking about it for a while in the context of my suggestion to use a `static async` method - or at least a static method returning a `Task<Foo>` - instead of a constructor. Take that idea, play with it for a while, then add a new question.